# Listing Latin Honor GPA while you are still undergraduate in your CV

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, gpa

I am wondering if my GPA is in the category of one of Latin honors like Cum Laude or Summa Cum Laude but I am still undergrad can I include Latin honors in CV while applying to graduate school?
This post is talking about this case however whoever asked the question did not specify whether he is still undergrad or graduate student.
[Honor Listed in undergrad. Should it go on the CV for grad applications ?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/30128/honor-listed-in-undergrad-should-it-go-on-the-cv-for-grad-applications)

Answer (score 19):

I would **not** include such a statement in your CV, since Latin honors are normally awarded at graduation. Until you have actually received the honors, don't list it in your CV. (Moreover, putting "eligible for *magna cum laude*" or the equivalent makes it look like you're trying too hard to list extra prizes, which reflects poorly on you.)

Comment: I think adding something like eligible would be fine. Undergraduate CVs are thin and I wouldn't look negatively on this.

Comment: I would.  I can read the number just fine, thanks.

Comment: @JeffE: Though the mapping "number -> latin phrase" is not well-defined, so "eligible for *magna cum laude*" gives you the extra information that this particular school considers this GPA sufficient for this honor.  Of course, you may or may not consider that information to be interesting.

Comment: So to conclude: based on what JeffE and aeismail and other said. should I include it in my CV or not?

Comment: @user59419 Clearly, they recommend you don't.